# Can I use already exist MySQL with xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I already installed MySQL 8.0 (port 3306) and using it. There's lot of data and else. Now I have to use php so I installed XAMPP, with MySQL that provides with install. I know that one server (MySQL or MySQL of XAMPP) should be stopped or change the port, but I want to use XAMPP with already existing MySQL. Can I do this? If I can do, how can I?

(I don't want to uninstall existing MySQL, but it's okay to uninstall XAMPP MySQL)

Comment: In your PHP script, you point to the existing MySQL server, not the XAMPP one.

Comment: So, did you try to google for remove mysql from xampp?

Comment: (1)Hint : there are two buttons for mysql in xampp admin panel (stop and config) (2) Strictly speaking this is not a coding-related question.

Comment: I did not remove it because I saw it is okay to install... but maybe I'll just remove it. And I searched for config (I tried to change port of xampp mysql but this is different server.) maybe i should try to solve in php script

Comment: But as we just do <?php $host='localhost' ... ?> this connects to xampp mysql. Isnt it?

Comment: "_this connects to xampp mysql_" Not really, no. This would connect to any mysqlserver running on your machine. You could run any number of mysqlservers on localhost (using different ports)

Comment: oooohhhh i corrected connection of php and it works. thank you.